# I want to make an html attribute that contains script but I can't manage "this" to go in to my script

Tags: javascript, scope, this

Problem with the scope of "this"
I want to make an html attribute that contains script but I can't manage "this" to go in to my script.

Thank you in advance!

```
<!-- html -->
<div script="console.log( 2 + 2 + ' -> ' + this)">
  <!-- some html -->
</div>

<script>
function scriptEval() {
    var script_elements = [];

    document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(attr => {
        if ("script" in attr.attributes) {
            script_elements.push(attr);
        }
    });
    script_elements.forEach(element => {
        var val = element.attributes.script.value;
        element.removeAttribute("script");
        val = eval(val);
    });

}
scriptEval();

// output
// 4 _ undefined

// I need
// 4 _ <div> ... </div> or whatever the this value is

</script>
```

Comment: You might want to consider not using the `eval()` function at all when dealing with JavaScript...

Comment: If you explain me why I might consider it. Thanks :)

Comment: It could be a security risk since you could potentially be calling `eval()` on a string that a hacker entered, which means that you will be executing raw JavaScript code that someone else created (injection). Even if you do good validations on strings, injections are still possible if you are using `eval()`. See here: https://medium.com/@eric_lum/the-dangerous-world-of-javascripts-eval-and-encoded-strings-96fd902af2bd

Comment: so you expect `this` to become the `.outerHTML` string of the element you are working on?

Comment: Yes, so I don't need to make script to get element by ID or whatever and then to apply the script to this element.  I want to make my own library as vue or angular  based on this functionality . "mattemyo" I didn't think for the injection thread but I think you are right :) . Now when I am writhing this I thing to myself .... what if I open to inspect the HTML of any website and find an img tag, change the url of the image with wrong one and add onerror event with any JS, that I want .... this will be technically the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out. I'm sorry to bother.
This is going to be in so much use!

> Pay attention in to the html script attribute.

the answer:

```
<!-- html -->
<div script="(e)=>{console.log(2 + 2 + ' -> ' + e)}">
  <p script="(e)=>{e.style.color = 'red'}">Some text that is not red</p>
  <div script="(e)=>{ [custume for loop iterator after fetch() applied on this div] }"></div>

</div>

<script>

 function scriptEval() {
    document.querySelectorAll("*[script]").forEach(element => {
        var val = element.attributes.script.value;
        element.removeAttribute("script");
        val = eval(val);
        return val(element);
    });
}
scriptEval();

// the output now
// 4 _ [object HTMLDivElement]

</script>
```